# URL in Alert body

Tags: ios

Can we put a tappable link in the alert body? Tapping the link should open the Mail client.
My pressing question is that has anyone tried it and is it accepted by apple.

The alert says *'Please contact Helpdesk for more information'* with an OK button - tap on 'helpdesk' and it should open the mail client.

Comment: A much better way would be to simply use "Send Mail" and "Cancel" as buttons. An "OK" alert with a obscure link in the body that you have to touch to trigger an action is bad UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Apple Documentation in regards to [UIAlertView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

> > **Subclassing Notes**
> >
> > The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

So to get the sort of customization you are talking about you would have to subclass `UIAlertView` which is not allowed, your app will be rejected.

However there are some alternatives to `UIAlertView` implementations that can be found [cocoa controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=alert&commit=Search).

You could just have a button that does the same as the link and than you could just use this method

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

To determine which button was pressed then run your mail client.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Use buttons for actions, not "links".

Answer (score 2):

I think While these kind of adding `customizations` to a `UIAlertView` is strongly discouraged by Apple You can Use the `UIAlertView` delegate Function to detect which `button` is pressed and can reaction on as required.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init withWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Your Event you want fire", nil];

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   switch(index)
        case 1:
              //fire Your Event you want fire
              break;
}
```

And if you looking some kind of change with `UIAlertView` One option will you cn create you own `Custom AlertView` try this [link SO Questions](http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy-ab&q=custom+uialertview+example+stackoverflow&oq=custom+uialertview+example+stack&gs_l=hp.3.0.33i29i30.33723.48083.6.48848.57.39.11.6.6.1.274.6935.0j33j6.39.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.2vHGbVxadHA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.bmk&fp=b9fcb73817f2160a&biw=1600&bih=756)

Comment: Its a client requirement - so some facts or documents would help my case.

Comment: @thiba you can create your own custom view like alertview

Comment: Thanks bit-whacker and Bhargavi. Could you please point me to some code or docs.

Comment: @Thiba as Bhargavi describe the right way And i also added links for Creating custom `UIAlertView`. Thanks Thida & Bhargavi

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911604/how-to-add-a-touchable-url-link-to-a-url-in-a-uialertviews-message

Comment: Thanks guys - have included this as an alternative to the present requirement!

Comment: @Thiba thanks but as i know as gave you answer first and there no more difference between the both answers ?