# How do I make an alert with a link in xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, app-store, uialertview, alert

I want to make an alert for the user when the ViewDidLoad loads and I want it to refer me to the App store where my paid app is, when I click it. What do I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a touchable Url link to a url in a UIAlertView's message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911604/how-to-add-a-touchable-url-link-to-a-url-in-a-uialertviews-message)

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` fires before your UI is displayed. You're going to want to place that code in `viewDidAppear`.